# @{ } {} operator in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware

Here's the code I've found in an Oracle SQL query:

```
EVALUATE('ADD_MONTHS(%1,-23)', date '@{p_date}{2016-01-01}')
```

As I understand it the query substracts 23 months from 2016-01-01 
date. What's going on with this @{p_date} part? I've checked and it seems that @ is not in any way reserved / operator expression in Oracle SQL.

My best quess is that `date '@{p_date}{2016-01-01}'` creates a local variable p_date of DATE type with value 2016-01-01 - and this trick is used to convert `'2016-01-01'` easily from string to date.
Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure this runs in SQL Developer? [`EVALUATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIVUG/GUID-7035040C-BB40-4392-920A-9A435593F659.htm#BILUG683) appears to be an Oracle Fusion Middleware function and is not part of the normal Oracle SQL syntax.

Comment: It's possible (I have only been given a text with  the code) - could you please tell me what does @{p_date}{2016-01-01} mean in this context?

Comment: `DATE '@{p_date}{2016-01-01}'` is a syntax error that throws an `ORA-01841` exception ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed3274ce4c584eedf585153b52c66522)). If you just want a date literal then use `DATE '2016-01-01'` in Oracle SQL. If there is additional markup in Oracle Fusion Middleware (if that is what this question is about) then you will need to tag the question appropriately so a subject-matter expert can answer it as I can't immediately spot that syntax in the documentation ... but at the moment the answer to your question is that it is not valid SQL.

Comment: I've retagged the question to include Oracle Fusion Middleware - if this is not what you are using then please revert the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much